# Error when trying to start a device in GNS3?

Tags: emulator

I have installed GNS3, I use the following image: c2691 IOS.image

So when I try to start the device 1st time, i get this error in the console:

```
=> ---------Traceback lines (saved in exception.log)----------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "GNS3\Scene.pyo", line 725, in slotStartNode

  File "GNS3\Node\IOSRouter.pyo", line 607, in startNode

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynagen.pyo", line 2542, in check_ghost_file

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynagen.pyo", line 2571, in _create_ghost_instance

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynamips_lib.pyo", line 3090, in __setghost_file

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynamips_lib.pyo", line 4998, in send

DynamipsError: 203-Bad number of parameters (3 with min/max=2/2)
```

On the subsequent attempts to start the same device, I get this error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
---------Traceback lines (saved in exception.log)----------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "GNS3\Scene.pyo", line 725, in slotStartNode

  File "GNS3\Node\IOSRouter.pyo", line 607, in startNode

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynagen.pyo", line 2542, in check_ghost_file

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynagen.pyo", line 2565, in _create_ghost_instance

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynamips_lib.pyo", line 2163, in __init__

  File "GNS3\Dynagen\dynamips_lib.pyo", line 4998, in send

DynamipsError: 206-unable to create VM instance 'ghost-c2691 IOS.image-127.0.0.1.ghost'

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

So any ideas how to resolve this?

EDIT:

Same happens on windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

> DynamipsError: 206-unable to create VM instance 'ghost-c2691 IOS.image-127.0.0.1.ghost'
>
> DynamipsError: 203-Bad number of parameters (3 with min/max=2/2)

This seems to be addressed in the [GNS3 FAQ](http://gns3vault.com/Faq/203-bad-number-of-parameters-1-with-minmax22.html).  If it is the same issue, ensure that your server‘s hostname and path to the image are correct.

Comment: Also see:http://commonerrors.blogspot.com/2013/10/baseconfigtxt-gns3-error-download.html

Comment: The first sugegstion I cannot do, as I can't even boot a device. And I tried second one, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: there shouldn't be a need to boot a device.  Make your corrections in the gns3 config file

Comment: As it turns out my lecturer gave me a faulty image file. I now was provided a proper one, and everything works :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: ok please add another answer to your question with this information